# バイナリファイルから引数に指定した1バイトに該当するバイトをすべて削除する

Tags: c++, バイナリファイル

C++での実装を教えてください．
引数は1バイトを16進数2桁で表したA3などの文字列を与えたいです．

Comment: どういった方法を考えていて、どのあたりの処理が判らないか問題点を明確にしてもらった方が回答が付きやすいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> バイナリファイルから引数に指定した1バイトに該当するバイトをすべて削除する

「引数に指定」をコマンドラインからの指定と理解したサンプルです。

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

bool fcopyExceptChar(const char* pi, const char* po, char dch)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(pi, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream ofs(po, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    if (ifs && ofs) {
        std::copy_if(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
            std::ostream_iterator<char>(ofs), [&dch](char ch) { return ch != dch; });
    }
    return !ifs.fail() && ofs;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 4) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " infile outfile except_byte" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    std::istringstream iss(argv[3]);
    unsigned dch = 0;
    iss >> std::hex >> dch;
    std::cout << "delbyte " << argv[1] << " to " << argv[2] << " except " << argv[3] << " ... " << std::flush;
    if (!fcopyExceptChar(argv[1], argv[2], dch)) {
        std::cerr << "\nError delbyte " << argv[1] << " to " << argv[2] << " except " << argv[3] << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    std::cout << "done!" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

コードを改善しました。
無駄なキャプチャーをなくし [&] を [&dch] へ
変数名 os を iss へ改善しました。